# Vert.x unmount subrouter

Tags: vert.x

I want to dynamically create, mount and unmount `io.vertx.ext.web.Router`s, based on certain events.

Creating a new router and mounting it is no problem using `Router::router` and `Router::mountSubRouter`. Every created subrouter will be added to a `java.util.Map` so they can be fetched later on, since there is no way to query the root `Router` for subrouters.

Howerver `Router` doesn't offer a function to unmount a subrouter. I can use `Router::clear` on the subrouter to remove all it's routes, but was wondering if there is a better way to unmount subrouters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
public static void unMountSubRouter(Router router, String root) {
    router.getRoutes().stream()
            .filter(route -> route.getPath() != null && route.getPath().startsWith(root))
            .forEach(route -> route.remove());
}
```